System goes to suspend mode when it is not supposed to
I use openSUSE Tumbleweed with kernel 6.11.8. A few weeks ago I noticed for the first time that the system went to suspend mode with no apparent reason. That happened maybe once every other day so it was not really annoying, an interruption of a few seconds so I just ignored it.
Yesterday I did a btrfs send (to a local file) on this system for the first time. While I was doing that the system went to suspend about every minute. In addition this caused chaos in the btrfs send: The "image" file of a subvolume with 20GiB data was about 200GiB in size... This was in dmesg and journalctl:
[Mo, 13. Jan 2025, 10:34:39] [   T1576] Lockdown: systemd-logind: hibernation is restricted; see man kernel_lockdown.7
[Mo, 13. Jan 2025, 10:34:39] [   T1576] Lockdown: systemd-logind: hibernation is restricted; see man kernel_lockdown.7
[Mo, 13. Jan 2025, 10:34:39] [   T1576] Lockdown: systemd-logind: hibernation is restricted; see man kernel_lockdown.7
[Mo, 13. Jan 2025, 10:34:39] [   T1821] wlan: deauthenticating from c0:4a:00:44:6e:d0 by local choice (Reason: 3=DEAUTH_LEAVING)
[Mo, 13. Jan 2025, 10:34:43] [T2358133] PM: suspend entry (s2idle)

I guess the funny date is a result of the nightly suspend somehow confusing some time measurement (the shown system time is OK).
I repeated the btrfs send with nice ionice -c3 and in that case there was not a single shutdown. The system has an NVMe. The problem seems not to be caused by CPU load (I piped the file through lbzip2 in the second run which put 15 cores to full usage...).
Is there any "official" cause of suspend mode which might get triggered here (without showing up in the logs)?
